# Using CSS to avoid tagging element that are inside the element

Tags: html, css

How do I avoid tagging css to the below code. I've tried a few things e.g. tried first:child but that didnt seem to work. I would just like the outer lis to be red not the second lis within the parent li

```css
li {
  color: red;
}
```

````html
<ul>
  <li>Tag this as red
    <ul>
      <li>
        Dont' tag this as color red
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Tag this as red
    <ul>
      <li>
        Dont' tag this as color red
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use direct child combinator `>` along with `initial`:

```css
ul>li {
  color: red;
}

ul>li>ul>li {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Tag this as red
    <ul>
      <li>
        Dont' tag this as color red
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Tag this as red
    <ul>
      <li>
        Dont' tag this as color red
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The reason you need to reset it on the inner `li`s is a) color is one of the inherited properties (any element will have the text color defined closest in its ancestor tree, unless it explicitly has a color set), and b) that `ul>li` will also match the inner `li`s.

Answer (score 1):

you can use just classes to separate each one of them

```css
.tagged-red {
  color: red;
}

.untagged-red {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tagged-red">Tag this as red
    <ul>
      <li class="untagged-red">
        Dont' tag this as color red
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="tagged-red">Tag this as red
    <ul>
      <li class="untagged-red">
        Dont' tag this as color red
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The child combinator `>` is placed between two CSS selectors. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the direct children of elements matched by the first. (for more information about **child combinator** you can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

But in your case, This doesn't work, because inner `<li>` inherits `color` from outer `<li>`, and both turn red.

```css
.outer{
  color:red;
}
.inner{
  color:initial;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="outer"> This shoud be red
      <ul>
        <li class="inner">
          This shoudn't be red
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="outer">  This shoud be red
      <ul>
        <li class="inner">
          This shoudn't be red
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

For more read about `inheritance` in `css`, you can read [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-inheritance-introduction/) article

Comment: That is exactly what my answer does, but it lacks your explanation of the problem. Well done, apart from the fact that your answer forces changing the HTML which isn't inherently necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use more specific selections, something like so:

```css
ul li {
 color: red;
}

ul li li {
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Tag this as red
        <ul>
            <li>
                Dont' tag this as color red
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
    <li>Tag this as red
        <ul>
            <li>
                Dont' tag this as color red
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I just tried that, didn't seem to work. It shows color as red.

Comment: I edited my response. Take a look.